# facebook Like button causes vertical scrollbar instead of overlaying

Tags: html, css, facebook, position, facebook-likebox

I added the facebook Like button to my website and am having an issue. When the Like button is clicked, the box that pops up doesn't overlay the other content like it does on most websites, instead creating a vertical scrollbar in the container (expanding it).

This issue actually exists on facebook's own website:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

If you scroll about half way down the above page and click the Like button, the same issue happens:

[image]

The only difference there is that they have overflow set to hidden, instead of auto.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your CSS file:
.fb-like{overflow:hidden;}

This should solve the problem.